# Get binding from listbox item label

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox in WPF which consists of few labels and a rectangle.

I am trying to get all the label values of items in a ListBox.

My WPF markup for ListBox is:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="izabraniList" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource izabraniIzbornik}" Margin="0,80,10,108" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="289" Background="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="izabraniIzbornik">
                <Border BorderBrush="white" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="254" Height="64" UseLayoutRounding="False" Opacity="100">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Rectangle Height="62" Width="62"
                            Margin="2,0"  RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" >
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=ART_SIFRA, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel Width="133" >
                            <Label Content="{Binding ART_NAZIV}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="left"
                            FontSize="12" Width="auto" Foreground="#FF303030" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="right" Width="55" Height="64">
                            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="top"  Height="20" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
                            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="bottom"  Height="64" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="55">
                                <Label x:Name="cijena" Content="{Binding SKC_PRICE}" FontSize="11" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Width="55" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding kolicina}" FontSize="11" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="top" FontWeight="Bold" Width="55" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
For Each i As String In izabraniList.Items("SKC_PRICE")
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

Comment: Where's the markup of your listbox? ANd why are you using `izabraniList.Items("SKC_CIJENA")` ..Did u try `izabraniList.Items` ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I am sorry, i have updated my question above.

Answer (score 0):

make a separate property in your class that flattens the list (i.e.

```
public string property { get { return String.Join(", ", izabranilist.Select(x => x.Skc_Price).toarray()); } }
```

and then bind that to the label.